# What does 'hack' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

"Hang it! take 'em **hack** to the ship!"

What does 'hack' mean in this sentence? I can't find the right meaning of 'hack' in my dictionary. In addition, What does 'hang it' mean?

[image]

Comment: The book's title is 'Mystery of the Tree House'. I think this book is very popular for the children in USA, I'm not native english speaker though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it asks about a misprint in a book.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Must be misprint of 'back'. The 'h' key is adjacent to the 'b' key on many keyboard layouts. The text later confirms this. This is repeated on the Google Books version of "Magic Tree House Fact & Fiction: Pirates" By Mary Pope Osborne and Will Osborne

[Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=i4loBAAAQBAJ&pg=PT29&lpg=PT29&dq=the%20pirate%20squinted%20his%20good%20eye%20aye%20lubber&source=bl&ots=uXBdXQzM2E&sig=_kDMjdZUarT3KA1Voaz5D9quaa8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjAg6uRqeDdAhVxZN8KHZAABXUQ6AEwAHoECBwQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20pirate%20squinted%20his%20good%20eye%20aye%20lubber&f=false)

Comment: Indeed, "Take 'em back to the ship".